# Global Coordinates Set (UTM Vs Geo)

Tags: c#, c++, gis

I got the impression from other programmers that GEO (wgs84) coordinates are not efficient
for calculating distance at meters resulotion.
My Goal is to calculate accuratly (meters) distance between 2 points (at the same country) by using global coordinates (UTM Or Geodetic(wgs84)) ,in which set of global coordinates
you recomand to use ??

thanks, 
Liran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve high precision in your calculations you should convert coordinates from WGS84 to country's local coordinate system. If you tell what country it is I could probably give a hint on what coordinate system is appropriate.

UPDATE: [This coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israeli_Transverse_Mercator) should work well for Israel. If you are using .NET you can use [Proj.NET](http://projnet.codeplex.com/) to convert coordinates. You will need a projection string for this coordinate system and it can be found [here](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2039/) - look for OGC WKT. This long string should be sent as the parameter in one of Proj.NET's methods.

Comment: The focused country is israel (but not always) , do you think converting wgs84 to utm will give high precision ? this is the impression i got..

Comment: If course - the earth has very different shapes in different parts, that's why each country has one ore sometimes even several(if country is big) coordinate systems.